# Did Calvin ever realise that Hobbes was not real?

Tags: comics, calvin-and-hobbes

In the comic strip *Calvin and Hobbes*, was there any moment where Calvin realised that Hobbes wasn't real?

Comment: Don't think so, but there are various versions by others that touch on this theme: https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-story-behind-the-fake-final-Calvin-and-Hobbes-strip

Comment: [But *is* he real...](http://literature.stackexchange.com/q/621/58)

Comment: @Mithrandir - Oh, [the feels.](http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1160193/images/o-GROWN-UP-CALVIN-AND-HOBBES-facebook.jpg). The [feeeeeels](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/0f/d2/f2/0fd2f21c66a19387182973d4f772ee94.png).

Comment: On what basis do you presume that Hobbes isn't real? The comic strip was always deliberately ambiguous on that point, and Watterson maintained the ambiguity when asked about it.

Comment: [No.](http://www.craveonline.com/images/stories/2011/2011/December/Comedy/calvin-hobbes-20-years/calvin-hobbes-grown-up-mom.jpg)

Comment: I don't think this use of the word "real" is the best fit. Are you claiming there is no stuffed animal? Of course, all parties agree that Hobbes is real. The question is, what is his nature.

Comment: Someone made [this comic](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/4a/cb/77/4acb774c08f5582ad8a2197bda567318.jpg) recently. It's more commentary than anything, but it's relevant to the question

Comment: There's a [meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10794/31936) as to whether or not Calvin and Hobbes is on topic.

Comment: @user151841 For now, we should probably restrict ourselves to the question of whether Hobbes is *alive*.  The question of what constitutes his essential nature is probably a bit too in-depth to resolve while not riding a toboggan.

Comment: This question seems to have struck a nerve.  To encourage dispassionate, on-topic responses, the question might be better phrased as "Does Calvin ever see Hobbes as a stuffed toy?".

Comment: You should watch some magician show, "mindfXck" or some of the thousand or so optical illusions you can find on the internet. Human perception is extremely flawed. The brain cheats on us and takes short cuts to explain reality for us all the time. You simply can't know what is or isn't real. There is no reason to label anything that can cause a change in a person as *unreal*. Because it is real by the simple definition that it clearly matters (to someone).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyXJfUPSQhM

Comment: Next you're gonna tell me that Woody & Buzz aren't real simply because Andy never sees them move.

Comment: What is "real"? How do you define "real"?

Comment: Sometimes, Calvin does realise that other people see just a stuffed toy, but Hobbes himself doesn't. http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lswkj26hY81qdp8pko1_500.gif

Comment: As it turns out, none of the characters are "real" - they're characters in a comic strip.  You're projecting your own perspective on reading the comics into the question, but that may not be real either.

Comment: @Scott If you mean that the question is lacking the phrase "in universe", just say so. Otherwise, let me state here for the record that the "fi" in "scifi" stands for "fiction" and that we're all aware of that.

Comment: Did the parents ever realise that Hobbes *was* real?

Comment: It was never established "in universe" that Hobbes was not real or really alive. So the question presumes something else from the op's perspective.

Comment: ["The idea of a Hobbes doll is especially noxious, because the whole intrigue of Hobbes is that he may or may not be a real tiger. The strip deliberately sets up two versions of reality without committing itself to either one."](http://www.tcj.com/the-bill-watterson-interview/) -- Bill Watterson. (He repeats the same point in the 10th anniversary collection, as I recall.)

Comment: I also noticed when re-reading the comics recently, that other people don't call Hobbes "a toy doll". They call him "a stuffed tiger", which is not quite the same, now is it!

Answer (score 228, accepted):

**The assumption in the question is mistaken.**

As @Mithical already linked above, it's a common assumption of adult readers that Hobbes couldn't possibly be real but [that's just not how the actual comic works](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/621/what-is-hobbes). Watterson intentionally left the entire issue unresolvable, with strips like this

[image: Comic with Calvin tied to a chair by Hobbes. Calvin's father finds Calvin tied up and has to untie him.]

where Hobbes should need to be real for Calvin to be in the situation he's in. The shift between how Calvin and his parents see the world is very real and part of what the comic explores, but Watterson didn't feel the parents were *right* and Calvin was *wrong*.

Comment: Was going to say that **I** have not arrived at that realization yet.

Comment: But see [this](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2017/03/29) and the previous strip where Calvin imagines he is a tiger but he actually isn't, and both his parents can see that he's just imagining things.

Comment: @user21820 - That is in no way different than Calvin seeing Hobbes as a real tiger and everyone else seeing him as a toy. Calvin has his reality in the comic, and everyone else has a different reality. You are demanding that the adult reality is the "true" one. But in the zeitgeist of the comic, this isn't the case. They simply coexist side-by-side. You are free to adopt one as your own, but that is you putting in an interpretation that Watterson clearly says he didn't intend.

Comment: His parents *think* he's just imagining things.

Comment: I don't know if I would go as far as to say it was impossible for Calvin to get himself in that situation.  I see that as a playful reminder of how some kids can get themselves into crazy, seemingly incomprehensible situations.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Where in my comment did I say that Calvin's reality is not real, even if it is in the mind?

Comment: @user21820 - You said so right here: "*Calvin imagines he is a tiger but he actually isn't*" and here: "*both his parents can see that he's just imagining things*". Mind you, there is nothing wrong with taking this interpretation - just as long as you keep in mind that it is your interpretation, not the author's, nor one that others necessarily should share.

Comment: I think **the storyline where Calvin duplicates himself** (and the duplicate makes several more copies) is an even better example of the two realities than Hobbes tying up Calvin.  Think about where the worms *came from* in the adult reality.  Then think about Calvin's reality.  Here, the disconnect is much stronger, but it's also subtle because the adults never investigate where Calvin got the worms.

Comment: Although not by Watterson, I like this old man Calvin story.  Once he's grown up and left imaginary friends behind.  http://www.tickld.com/x/this-guy-just-changed-the-way-we-seecalvin-and-hobbes

Comment: @Wildcard Do you have a link to that story, by chance?

Comment: @MissMonicaE: [Here's the strip](http://3e.org/feeds/ch/90/ch900130.gif). [Here's the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0836218787). If you haven't read it already, do.

Comment: @lly Thank you! :)

Comment: Calvin doing things which seem to be impossible to pull off alone are not necessarily proof that Hobbes is real. It can be a joke of how many surprising and unexplained things a 5 year old child can do. I've seen small children find hidden things and crawl into places I wouldn't have thought possible before.

Comment: @vsz And that's the "he doesn't think *Calvin* is right and his parents are wrong" side of the same coin.

Comment: I don't know if anyone will click through to see all this, but someone posted a follow-up question: [Does Hobbes ever do anything that Calvin himself could not do?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156596/does-hobbes-ever-do-anything-that-calvin-himself-could-not-do) [The short answer is 'yes', but mostly within Calvin's perspective so you can handwave it if you like being adult about the whole thing.]

Comment: There is always Bacon and Hobbes: http://www.pantsareoverrated.com/archive/2011/05/10/hobbes-and-bacon/

Answer (score 87):

**No.**

Calvin's parents mostly play along with his belief Hobbes is real. But when Susie directly points out that Hobbes is a stuffed toy, Calvin simply ignores her:

[image: Calvin and Hobbes-in-doll-form are fighting in the grass. Susie walks by, saying "I don't know what's weirder - that you're fighting a stuffed animal, or that you seem to be losing." Calvin responds "I'M NOT LOSING! HOBBES CHEATS! Quit it, you! Ow! Stop it!"]

In the very last panel of the comic, we see Calvin as convinced as ever that Hobbes is a real tiger:

[image: Calvin and Hobbes are out with the tobbogan in freshly-fallen snow. They discuss the fresh start and possibilities of the new year and a new day. Calvin says "It's a magical world, Hobbes, ol' buddy... let's go exploring!", and Calvin and Hobbes ride off into the distance.]

Comment: Surely I'm not the only one that expected Calvin to start "writing" in the snow at the end...

Comment: Somewhere, in one of my boxes of old work stuff, I have a framed copy of that last panel.  I should dig it out and hang it up here at home.

Comment: I think this is more conclusive proof that Hobbes is not real: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ba/88/34/ba8834c5302faf4ae1bc649ecdafe72e.jpg

Comment: Conversely, here is more proof that he IS real. Calvin often imagines things, often lives in his own fantasy world. And the strip's format is so that the whole comic is set in this fantasy world of his, except for the last panel, which is set in the real world. And sure enough, Hobbes is real in the last panel more often than not. [Example](http://68.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lyl6naPIg91qdp8pko1_1280.gif). So Hobbes is not part of Calvin's imaginary world.

Answer (score 30):

What makes you think that he's *not* real?

First, consider what you mean by "real." If you mean "could you put a video camera there and record Hobbes doing the things that the comic strip has him doing with Calvin?", that's deliberately left ambiguous in the comic strips. In fact, even in a strip where Calvin takes photographs of Hobbes, Calvin and his dad just see the pictures differently, so it resolves nothing - it's not clear what the pictures "really" look like.

I'm not convinced that the "video-camera approach" is the best way to view this, though. Try to view it through the characters' POV. From Calvin's POV, yeah, he's real. From the other characters' POV, he's a stuffed tiger. I don't think that it's really important (or provable from the comic strip) which one is "correct" in the video camera sense.

Comment: I hope you recall the strip where Calvin takes pictures of Hobbes making goofy faces?  Video cameras prove absolutely nothing, either.

Comment: (Since when did cameras become arbiters of reality, anyway?)

Comment: @Wildcard That's true, it had slipped my mind :) - weren't his parents looking at the pictures at the time, though?

Comment: Calvin and his dad both look, with different results.  [See for yourself](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ba/88/34/ba8834c5302faf4ae1bc649ecdafe72e.jpg).

Comment: What is "film"?  (Just kidding)

Comment: There is one strip where Calvin takes a photo of Hobbes pouncing as the front door is opened.  His dad accuses him of throwing Hobbes up in the air and taking a picture of it.

Comment: @Perkins: that's feb 27 1994: https://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/1994/02/27

Answer (score 8):

As far as I understood when I read Calvin and Hobbes, the situations Calvin finds himself are always ambiguous. One could choose to believe that Calvin just has a high imagination in his role play with his stuffed toy or one could believe that Hobbes is some kind of magical toy that comes to life only for Calvin and is a stuffed toy to the rest of them. something like Perry in "Phineas and Ferb" (just the concept not the stuffed part).

And I always read these comics from the second point of view because it makes it that much more fun. Especially since we never hear dialogues from Hobbes when there are other people around. All his interactions are mostly done when they are alone.

Comment: I seem to remember Calvin arguing with Hobbes in front of Suzie Derkins.  Calvin obviously hears Hobbes' comments, but Suzie doesn't, and they don't appear in the comic panel.

Comment: could you give me a link to that particular strip?

Comment: In all the ones i remember, calvin is generally caught reacting by others to something hobbes has already done when others were not observing. So it appeared as though calvin was talking to his toy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know of an easy way to find the strip online.  I'm about to reread the books, though, so I'll say what book and page if I find it.

Comment: @Wildcard http://calvinandhobbes-daily.tumblr.com/

Answer (score -1):

I'd argue yes, in this strip (May 20, 1986):

[image: Calvin and Hobbes are taking a hike and talking about how seeing wildlife. Calvin suddenly says "Look! A tiger!" Hobbes freaks out, jumping in the air and tail puffing up. They stand in silence for a panel before Hobbes (the tiger) scolds, "Don't DO that!"]

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site! Could you add any explanation as to why you'd argue yes on the basis of this strip :S Really looks like he's playing a trick on the tiger he thinks is there by pretending he can see another one which he knows isn't there

Comment: @Au101 I think this is meant to imply that Hobbes is not a real tiger, because there's almost no reason a real tiger would be so startled when he is notified of another tiger.

Comment: @Gallifreyan It could also be because hobbes is a tame tiger who lives with calvin and is afraid of a more carnivorous tiger especially living in wild. So this is NOT a proof that Calvin realized Hobbes was not a real tiger.

Comment: Sure, the obvious implication here is just that Hobbes is a "housecat" so he jumps at wild tigers.

Comment: I find it really interesting that everyone else reads this differently - I've always interpreted that strip as him pointing *at* Hobbes, because he knows Hobbes will instinctively assume he means *another*, wild tiger.

Comment: @tardigrade I guess that is logical too!

Answer (score -5):

The simple answer is: No, he hasn't.

All the answers stating the ambiguity of Watterson's writing are over-thinking the concept of Hobbes, which is that he is real in the eyes of Calvin and Calvin alone.

I would like to point out this strip:

[image: Hobbes: "So you're a tiger now?" Calvin, inside the transmogrifier box: "Yep. Let me out." Hobbes lifts the box, and a Calvin-sized tiger stands there looking up at Hobbes. They look at each other for a panel, and then Hobbes says "Words fail me." Calvin, looking down at himself, responds "I'm disappointed too, but keep in mind transmogrification is a new technology."]

Comment: Can you offer any evidence that this is the case? As written it seems like your *personal* opinion

Comment: As is evident by Panels such as @Royal Canadian Bandit's example. It is not an opinion, it is clearly shown that it is how Calvin sees Hobbes, same with Spaceman Spiff

Comment: As has been pointed out (by me, in the cross-site duplicate) there are also instances where Hobbes appears to have undertaken actions that Calvin couldn't have managed on his own. Reaching high objects, for example, or tying up Calvin with ropes.

Comment: But you do not see Hobbes performing these acts, right?

Comment: Not as far as I can recall, but then I haven't read every C&H comic ever written

Comment: Haha, that is a very fair point! Although its sad to think we eventually will

Comment: I don't understand the previous three comments at all, from Nonagon and @Valorum.

Comment: Fwiw, Hobbes is shown as a real tiger, alongside a real bunny, at a tea party with Susie. It's more about childish imagination than Calvin's magic/personal imagination/psychosis.

Comment: I joined this SE for the sole purpose of upvoting your answer and writing this comment. I won't bother to downvote the other ones. I'm just feeling that I'm living a *very* bad nightmare right now. What is the chance of humankind ever resolving its problems if educated individuals with the means to access the internet give the answers above and upvote them? And I'm extremely serious. There is always hope that political and psychological differences can be worked out through logic, persuasion and reality testing - until one sees the reality testing that takes place in this no-stakes discussion.

Comment: http://calvinandhobbes-daily.tumblr.com/image/38571036760

Comment: @Nonagon isnt that the whole point of mystery with the tiger? the fact that he could be coming alive only when he is alone with calvin is itself magical/unexplained. So it could be that its temporaray scientific achievement and calvin changes back to himself when he finally finds others as is the case in many comedic scenes of other fictions where some great achievement gets conveniently destroyed just to fit it in real world scene.

Comment: @Dev I always saw it as the world through the eyes of a child with a great imagination. But people seem to want it to be literal

Comment: @Nonagon if some people seem to want it to be literal, then some people think its just his imagination. That is why the plot is always written in such a way that both sides could be absolutely true which is what makes it fun to read.

Comment: I've locked this to prevent a rollback/edit war, and rolled it back to the more accessible version.

Answer (score -7):

Some answers are stating what the comic's author intended which is the characters never actually state this.  Some may claim Susie does, but the conversation is between Calvin and her so from the reader's perspective it's a he said/ she said scenario and can't reliably answer the realness of Hobbes.  Also, what an author's intent for their work doesn't matter.  If what they write leads most readers to interpret the words differently, then they are horrible writers and couldn't convey the meaning they intended.  What we can say to answer this question, at no time is it illustrated in the comics that Calvin views Hobbes as anything other than a "real" tiger.  Anything else outside those panels is pure speculation including the author's intent.

Comment: Take a look at our [tour], you will find we prefer answers supported by facts rather than opinion based "rants". Feel free to [edit] your answer to make it more factual.

Comment: An author's intent most certainly does matter. This idea that a work of art, once free into the world, is a wholly separate entity from the creator is revisionist bunk, designed to allow poseurs to contradict the obvious

Comment: Intent doesn't matter.  What does matter is what the reader understands when he reads the words you choose to put down. Suppose I wrote you a note that says "I will meet you on Thursday".  I give the note to you on Monday.  On Wednesday, I see you and ask "Where were you yesterday?"  You wouldn't have any idea what I was talking about.  If you point that out to me and I respond with "I intended to say 'Tuesday'".  It won't change what you actually wrote and what you understood when you read it.

Comment: Fact: Calvin and Susie have an adversarial relationship.  Fact: Calvin treats Hobbes as real.  Fact: At no point I have seen does Calvin state he understands Hobbes is a toy.  Fact: If you what your understanding from the words that are written are different from what the author intended, the author needed to choose different words.  I'm not sure what you think is opinion or a "rant".

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're saying in the comments, you will need to change the words of the answer.

Comment: @user99448 Intent does matter.  Your Tuesday/Thursday analogy is a result of incorrectness, not ambiguity.  Watterson went out of his way to leave this ambiguous, that does not make him "a horrible writer."  Ambiguity and leaving room for interpretation is horrible in a reference manual, but can be a powerful tool in fiction.

Comment: Y'all, the discussion over whether the author's intent matters or doesn't stems back as far as [The Death of the Author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_the_Author) if not further (and it almost certainly *does* extend back further). There isn't an objectively correct answer, so this "yes it does" / "no it doesn't" argument as if there's a factually correct stance is a waste of all of your time. Whether the intent matters or not are two different analytical lenses which can *both* be valid when applied well.